# javascript/css: change display property

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change display without documentGetElementById if possible but the following is not working.
html

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="toggleFaq('1')">Instructions</a><div id="showfaq1" style="display:none;">Open Box.  Remove device. </div>
```

javascript:

```
function toggleFaq(faqid) {
//alert(faqid);
var divname = "showfaq"+faqid;
//alert(divname);
divname.style.display="block";
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: that's not possible. Either use getElementById, getElementByTagName etc. or jQuery.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a good way of doing this and instead using implicitly bound inline js?

Comment: If you provide more information on why you don't want to use `getElementById`, you would get better suggestions.

Comment: I guess I misremembered that it was possible to do this w/o getElementById.  Just wanted to do with as little js as possible.  Stand corrected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can't get why you do not want to use `getElementById`, but...

If you have elements in order like this

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="toggleFaq('1')">Instructions</a>
<div id="showfaq1" style="display:none;">Open Box.  Remove device. </div>
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="toggleFaq('2')">Instructions</a>
<div id="showfaq2" style="display:none;">Open Box.  Remove device. </div>
...
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="toggleFaq('N')">Instructions</a>
<div id="showfaqN" style="display:none;">Open Box.  Remove device. </div>
```

You may use

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="toggleFaq(this)">Instructions</a>
```

---

```
function toggleFaq(obj) {
   obj.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: I'd better go for `nextElementSibling` or check for `nextSibling.nodeType === 1`

Comment: better use setAttributes(),  `obj.nextSubling.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;')`. this way you can change class or what ever..

Answer (score 1):

In your code `divname` is a variable containing a string "showfaq1", which doesn't have `style` property.

To change the style of an element you need a reference to that element which you can obtain using `document.getElementById(divname)`:

```
function toggleFaq(faqid) {
    //alert(faqid);
    var divname = "showfaq"+faqid;
    //alert(divname);
    document.getElementById(divname).style.display="block";
}
```

If you have an allergy to `document.getElementById`, you may use `document.querySelector('[id="' + divname +'"]');`, but its support is not as good as the former, and it's slower.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a separate answer as it has no impact on my previous one. But you could make the base mechanism without JS at all, then use one of the JS-based solutions to fix it in broken browsers if needed:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#showfaq1">Instructions</a>
<div id="showfaq1">Open Box.  Remove device. </div>
```

**CSS**

```
a + div { display:none; }
a:focus + div, a + div:target { display:block; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwUXN/)